# Google authenticator for desktop

Tags: authentication

Is there a desktop application for Google authenticator (an equivalent to the phone app, not the PAM lib)?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There are Java apps, both [GUI](https://github.com/mclamp/jauth#readme) and [CLI](http://blog.jcuff.net/2011/02/cli-java-based-google-authenticator.html). Both were listed on the [Google Authenticator page at Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Authenticator). Both include install instructions on their respective download pages.

I like the idea but I have not tested either of these nor would I assume they are secure or even work correctly. This is a summary of my search results, not a recommendation.

Comment: Cool, thank you. It's too bad these are not provided with the google-authenticator code. Also, I wonder if it would be easy to make some kind of desktop widget with multiple account/key pairs, maybe using another language ;-)

Comment: @Raphink yes, maybe a dead simple appindicator that would drop down a small menu with the code(s)? Maybe it's best to require two different devices to log in from a security perspective though. I'm very reluctant to trade security for convenience.

Comment: An appindicator would be very nice indeed. Porting the code to another language (e.g. python) shouldn't be too hard. As for several devices… well there's still the password. I don't really see a problem with having the authenticator on the desktop as far as security goes.

Comment: To be clearer, the main security feature of TOTP imo is to prevent login/password remote attacks, not so much local attacks using the 1 or 2 machines I use every day.

Answer (score 24):

Simply install the small command line utility `oathtool`.

`sudo apt-get install oathtool`

Then run such a command to get a one time password:

`oathtool --totp -b YOURSECRET`

Comment: For further instructions, read this https://thirld.com/blog/2016/01/16/generating-two-factor-authentication-codes-on-linux/

Comment: If I have the google authenticator on my phone, where do I get the SECRET from?

Comment: Good! I will make a GUI problem based on this then post it here too!

Comment: This answer is great, but I don't like ending with 2FA secrets in my Bash history. Is there a more secure way to invoke oathtool that I might be missing?

Comment: @MarcelHernandez You can define an alias for the command and put it in `.bashrc`, but then the secret will be stored in that file. There's no way to generate OTP and *not* store the corresponding secret somewhere. If you want true 2FA, then the only way to achieve that is to use a separate device, like a phone, for OTP.

Comment: Since I asked this question I found and settled on the pass password manager with the OTP plugin https://www.passwordstore.org/ https://github.com/tadfisher/pass-otp

Comment: @MarcelHernandez no more of interest for you,  but add this to your .bashrc avoid sensitive info going into history

export HISTCONTROL=ignorespace .. more info here:

https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Variables.html

Answer (score 13):

You can use some Extension for your web browser, they work pretty good.

Here you go, here's an example:

[image]

For Chrome/Chromium/Yandex (and other Chrome based browsers) you can use Authenticator. Just click on "Add to Chrome" button from [this link](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/authenticator/bhghoamapcdpbohphigoooaddinpkbai?hl=en-US).

Or you can add it through: `Customise and control` menu (three dashes/dots upper right corner of the browser) > `Settings` > `Extensions` > `Get more extensions` (in the bottom of the list) > `Search the store` for: `Authenticator`.

You need to [add a Passphrase](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gzhfq.png). This step will allow you to sync multiple instances - transfer of the authentication data between computers which you use with your Google account.

To add an authentication key: First [click here](https://www.google.com/chart?chs=250x250&chld=M%7C5&cht=qr&chl=otpauth://totp/key@name%3Fsecret%3DYOURFSECRETFCODE) to open a demo barcode in your browser. Then follow next steps for: [Scan QR code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lj9vR.png) or [Manual entry](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iZNdV.png). If the barcode is not generated by some Google application, for most cases you must use only Manual entry. If the authentication code is time based you must use [Sync Clock with Google](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q5SJv.png) function.

To [use the application](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hYStz.png), just click on the Authenticator icon. Wait for the beginning of a new cycle. Click on the new generated key. It will be copied to the clipboard.

Use the key! Usually *you have about a minute* and a half to use it.

I'm not so familiar with other browsers, but for example, within Firefox in a similar way you can use [Open Two-Factor Authenticator](https://addons.mozilla.org/bg/firefox/addon/open-two-factor-authenticator/).

---

In addition, the next answers describe how to implement Two Factor Authentication (using Google Authenticator) within Apache2 and OpenSSH:

- [How to secure phpmyadmin](https://askubuntu.com/questions/938398/how-to-secure-phpmyadmin/939241#939241)
- [Secure an Ubuntu OpenSSH server from Brute force attacks but without a firewall or SSH key pair?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/903911/secure-an-ubuntu-openssh-server-from-brute-force-attacks-but-without-a-firewall/904035#904035)

Comment: Thank for this hint, I installed it on Ubuntu Chrome Browser. To import my Google Auth accounts, I had to take a picture of the QR in my phone with another phone (screenshot is forbidden in Google Auth App) and send it to my Ubuntu where I put it on my localhost, where I could scan it with the extension. Cumbersome but working :)

Answer (score 1):

You could also try [authenticator](https://pypi.org/project/authenticator/)

To install, just type:

```
pip3 install authenticator
```

You could add accounts using

```
authenticator add MyAccount
```

At first it will ask you to create data files (say yes), then ask for a password to secure your otp secrets (required).
After you confirm your password, it will ask for the secret code to generate the one time password.
To generate an OTP:

```
authenticator gen MyAccount
```