# Google authenticator for Galaxy Nexus with Ubuntu Touch

Tags: ubuntu-touch, android, authentication, google, galaxy-nexus

I'm en route to try and [install ubuntu touch](http://www.ubuntu.com/phone/install) on my galaxy nexus (GSM-i9250). Since I'm using the google authenticator app in order to access my google account, I'm afraid that I'll be locked out of my accounts, has the installation of ubuntu touch succeeds.

Aside from printing the codes that google provides me with, I wonder if there is some kind of an app for google authenticator for ubuntu touch, or any other workaround that will allow me to access my account? I assume I won't be able to access google play from ubuntu touch, so I won't be able to reinstall the native google authenticator app.

Please note that my question is somehow similar to [this one](https://askubuntu.com/questions/182498/google-authenticator-for-the-desktop), only I need to use google authenticator on my phone, and not on my laptop, since I don't always have it with me.

Answer (score 1):

There is an app called Authenticator in the Store that does just that.

Comment: Link would be helpful.