# Installing features on Ubuntu

Tags: server, aws

I've installed Magento2 on Ubuntu using ssh on AWS EC2. However I would like the niceties of a control panel such as cPanel/Plesk to make things easier.

I've read that cPanel is not supported, can Plesk be used and is it a good alternative for someone not too familiar with Linux commands?

Is there any other way of remoting into Linux which provides a UI ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

[Webmin](http://www.webmin.com/) is a good alternative. I'm using it with [two factor authentication](https://askubuntu.com/a/803907/566421) and [Authentic Theme](http://www.webmin.com/cgi-bin/search_third.cgi?themes=1). Here you are a screenshot:

[image: Webmin screenshot]

**Update:** According to [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/860247/installing-features-on-ubuntu#comment1326571_860266) comment, the new Webmin's version 1.831 with Authentic Theme 18.32 already has and "live" sh terminal window.

Answer (score 1):

I've used webmin way back, it used to use too much resources. I didn't like it but can't judge the current version, the last time I used webmin was easily 6+ years ago.

On my servers, I don't use any Cpanel, if the client insist then I do it for him. Plesk is really good. If you want one that is free, [VestaCP](https://vestacp.com/) is an option, I tried it for a client, I was impressed

Comment: I don't think that current version of Webmin consumes significant amount of resources. VestaCP looks nice. Would it be open a (live) terminal window there without java enabled browser? Webmin can't do that and for me it will be advantage for VestaCP.

Comment: @SpasSpasov unfortunately I can't answer this question since I've never used the terminal  that they offer and don't have access to a vestacp machine right now to test that for you