# Can I run Google Authenticator from Ubuntu without a cellphone?

Tags: security

I'm running Kubuntu 21.10.  Can I run Google Authenticator without needing a cellphone?

Comment: You want to run Google Authenticator in Kubuntu instead of your cellphone?

Comment: Is an Android Emulator an option...? That might work. Or, [there are Google Authenticator alternatives](https://www.reddit.com/r/linuxquestions/comments/90lkk3/twofactor_authentication_client_for_gnulinux/) that run on desktop Linux

Comment: While you can't run google authenticator from linux, you may be able to replicate it's functionality. For instance, if you are trying to authenticate using an OTP seed, you can use the oathtool to generate your OTP code from a seed. For OTP seeds, most interfaces provide something that you can click to get an ascii code from a QR code, otherwise you can scan the code from you phone and then key it into oathtool.

Comment: @CharlesS If you need to scan a QR code with a phone you need to have and use a phone! The question is "Can I run Google Authenticator without needing a cellphone?"

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Google authenticator for desktop](https://askubuntu.com/questions/182498/google-authenticator-for-desktop)

Comment: The search term you want is ‘TOTP’, that’s the name for the standard that GA uses to generate codes. Most decent password managers support it these days, so you likely will not have to look far.

Comment: You can install KeePassXC and simply add TOTP to your entry.
Here's some nice in-depth tutorial:
https://www.linux.org/threads/in-depth-tutorial-how-to-set-up-2fa-totp-with-keepassxc-aegis-and-authy.36577/

Answer (score 8):

If you can obtain the image with the QR code containing the secret, you can achieve the functionality of Google Authenticator with a handful of command-line tools.

The image with the QR code can be scanned using [`zbarimg`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/jammy/en/man1/zbarimg.1.html) (or [`zbarcam`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/jammy/en/man1/zbarcam.1.html)), available in the [zbar-tools](https://packages.ubuntu.com/jammy/zbar-tools) package.  Scanning will return an URI much like the following:

```text
otpauth://totp/PROVIDER:ACCOUNT?secret=SECRET&algorithm=ALGO&digits=N&period=MM
```

Words written above in capitals are variables that you will need to extract from your actual code.  To generate tokens, you can invoke [`oathtool`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/jammy/en/man1/oathtool.1.html) (from the [oathtool](https://packages.ubuntu.com/jammy/oathtool) package) from the command line, like so:

```sh
oathtool --totp=ALGO -b SECRET -d N -s MM
```

The above assumes tokens are generated in TOTP mode (as most are).  `oathtool` supports HOTP mode as well, which I am not describing here; generating tokens in that mode is a little more involved, as you need to store the number of times a token has been generated, but is still doable.  Look at the relevant manpages for more information.

For secret storage and retrieval, you can use for example [`secret-tool`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/jammy/en/man1/secret-tool.1.html) from the [libsecret-tools](https://packages.ubuntu.com/jammy/libsecret-tools) package (to store in the GNOME keyring), or any other vault tool you like.

Answer (score -1):

No.

[Google Authenticator](https://googleauthenticator.net/) specifically uses a phone for the 2-step verification. The second step is a code sent to your phone.

You can choose to "keep it simple":

> **During sign-in, you can choose not to use 2-Step Verification again on that particular computer.** From then on, that computer will only ask for your password when you sign in.
>
> You'll still be covered, because when you or anyone else tries to sign
> in to your account from another computer, 2-Step Verification will be
> required.

Comment: Google Authenticator is a simple TOTP system and there are several PC implementations for it, like for example in KeePass.

Comment: @allo Yes, but please read again the question. Also try to understand who's asking.